# Can Gmail recognise threads/conversations with non-English reply prefixes?

Tags: gmail, gmail-conversations

In Gmail, when I receive a reply to a message with `Subject: X`, and the reply has `Subject: Re: X`, it correctly recognises it as a reply and sorts the message in the same thread/conversation.

However, if the reply has a subject `Aw: X` or `Sv: X`, as may happen when people use non-English e-mail clients, Gmail appears to not recognise the message as part of the conversation.

Is it possible to tune or configure Gmail to make it understand non-English reply prefixes?

If so, how?

Comment: I imagine this might be dependent on whatever language is set as the "Gmail display language"...? Would "Aw: X" and "Sv: X" be two _different_ languages?

Comment: Yes. Aw would be German, Sv would be Norwegian or Swedish. I communicate in multiple languages.

Comment: And if your display language is set as German and you get a reply as "Aw: X", is it grouped as a conversation? Or does it make no difference? I'm not saying this is an answer, just trying to figure out what Gmail is doing. I assume conversations do work in other languages, since it is a key part of how Gmail works. But I could understand that it might only work for one language at a time (although I could be wrong). Gmail currently supports 57 languages, so I imagine there is quite a variety of prefixes.

Comment: Though it doesn't help your problem, the "Re:" is actually supposed to be Latin for "in the matter of", not English for "Reply", see section 3.6.5 of http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html.  So the world is wrong, sort of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be using the `References:` header of the email messages.  However, not all email clients provide a correct References header.  There is nothing you can do about Gmail's processing of the mail headers.

Some references:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Header_fields
- http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2629
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28017

Comment: It seems my issue is mostly when people use Microsoft Outlook...